# Артефакты Youtube, фризы ОС

Tags: железо, видеокарта

Появились следующие артефакты при воспроизведении видео на Youtube.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q6DjLSZx3tY

Проблемы периодически появляется, после продолжительной работы системы.
В Диспетчере задач, GPU 3D под 100%, мне эти артефакты напоминают поврежденные JPEG файлы.
Если свернуть вкладку с видео - нагрузка на видео карту падает.
Так же бывают фризы без воспроизведения видео, в том же хроме, к примеру, во время скрола и в других приложения (GPU 3D под 100%).
Были различные программные ошибки в ОС, поэтому переустановил Windows, программные ушли, это вот осталось.

Я так понимаю - видеокарта накрывается?
Можно ли что-то сделать?
Есть ли смысл нести в ремонт?
Может ли быть проблема в другом устройстве?

Железо

```
Компьютер:
Тип компьютера Компьютер с ACPI на базе x64
Операционная система Microsoft Windows 10 Pro

Системная плата:
Тип ЦП HexaCore Intel Core i7-8700, 4300 MHz (43 x 100)
Системная плата Gigabyte Z370M DS3H (2 PCI-E x1, 1 PCI-E x16, 1 M.2, 4 DDR4 DIMM, Audio, Video, Gigabit LAN)
Чипсет системной платы Intel Kaby Point Z370, Intel Coffee Lake-S
Системная память 65483 МБ (DDR4 SDRAM)
DIMM1: Kingston HyperX KHX3200C18D4/16G 16 ГБ DDR4-3200 DDR4 SDRAM (22-21-21-39 @ 1600 МГц) (21-21-21-39 @ 1600 МГц) (20-21-21-39 @ 1600 МГц) (19-21-21-39 @ 1600 МГц) (18-21-21-39 @ 1600 МГц) (17-20-20-37 @ 1511 МГц) (16-19-19-35 @ 1422 МГц) (15-18-18-33 @ 1333 МГц) (14-17-17-31 @ 1244 МГц) (13-16-16-28 @ 1155 МГц) (12-14-14-26 @ 1066 МГц) (11-13-13-24 @ 977 МГц) (10-12-12-22 @ 888 МГц) (9-11-11-20 @ 800 МГц)
DIMM2: Kingston Fury KF3200C16D4/16GX 16 ГБ DDR4-3000 DDR4 SDRAM (18-17-17-36 @ 1501 МГц) (17-17-17-36 @ 1501 МГц) (16-17-17-36 @ 1501 МГц) (15-17-17-36 @ 1501 МГц) (14-16-16-34 @ 1401 МГц) (13-15-15-32 @ 1301 МГц) (12-14-14-29 @ 1201 МГц) (11-13-13-27 @ 1101 МГц) (10-12-12-24 @ 1001 МГц) (9-11-11-22 @ 900 МГц)
DIMM3: Kingston HyperX KHX3200C16D4/16GX 16 ГБ DDR4-3000 DDR4 SDRAM (18-17-17-36 @ 1501 МГц) (17-17-17-36 @ 1501 МГц) (16-17-17-36 @ 1501 МГц) (15-17-17-36 @ 1501 МГц) (14-16-16-34 @ 1401 МГц) (13-15-15-32 @ 1301 МГц) (12-14-14-29 @ 1201 МГц) (11-13-13-27 @ 1101 МГц) (10-12-12-24 @ 1001 МГц) (9-11-11-22 @ 900 МГц)
DIMM4: Kingston Fury KF3200C16D4/16GX 16 ГБ DDR4-3000 DDR4 SDRAM (18-17-17-36 @ 1501 МГц) (17-17-17-36 @ 1501 МГц) (16-17-17-36 @ 1501 МГц) (15-17-17-36 @ 1501 МГц) (14-16-16-34 @ 1401 МГц) (13-15-15-32 @ 1301 МГц) (12-14-14-29 @ 1201 МГц) (11-13-13-27 @ 1101 МГц) (10-12-12-24 @ 1001 МГц) (9-11-11-22 @ 900 МГц)
Тип BIOS AMI (07/05/2018)

Дисплей:
Видеоадаптер NVIDIA GeForce GTX 950 (2 ГБ)
3D-акселератор nVIDIA GeForce GTX 950
Монитор Philips 245E1 [24" LCD] (303916069)
Монитор Samsung SyncMaster S22C150 [22" LCD] (HLND900532)

Мультимедиа:
Звуковой адаптер nVIDIA GM206 HDMI/DP @ nVIDIA GM206 - High Definition Audio Controller
Звуковой адаптер Realtek ALC887 @ Intel Kaby Point PCH - High Definition Audio Controller (Audio, Voice, Speech)

Хранение данных:
IDE-контроллер Стандартный контроллер SATA AHCI
Контроллер хранения данных Контроллер дискового пространства (Майкрософт)
Контроллер хранения данных Стандартный контроллер NVM Express
Дисковый накопитель ST2000DM008-2FR102 (2 ТБ, 5000 RPM, SATA-III)
Дисковый накопитель TOSHIBA DT01ACA100 (1 ТБ, 7200 RPM, SATA-III)
Дисковый накопитель TS512GMTE110S (512 ГБ, PCI-E 3.0 x4)
SMART-статус жёстких дисков OK
```

Comment: похоже, просто перегревается все. я бы корпус почистил. А собственно сам Ютуб последнее время очень стал любить греть процессор. прям во всю

Comment: перегрева нет. и грузит не процессор, а видеокарту.

Comment: современные видеокодеки умеют и через видеокарту декодировать видео. Но я бы как минимум осмотрел видеокарту, проверил ее температуру и ещё проверил бы кабель к монитору. У меня были странные артефакты на мониторе, а оказалось, что просто кабель немного выскочил с разъёма. Чуть столом пошевелишь - и по экрану странные шумы и кубики.